# Is it possible to use variable Tag Name in VB.Net XML Axis query

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml, axis, xelement

Is it possible to use variable tag name in VB.Net XML Axis query???

e.g. contacts....<**varTag**>.Value

Where "varTag" is variable name and the real tag name will be known at only runtime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with the VB.NET XML axis syntax, but you can use the [`Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) method (just write `.Element(varTag)` instead of `.<varTag>`)